# Let $f:L \rightarrow L$ be a diagonalizable operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

This is a question from the book "*Linear Algebra and Geometry*", of Kostrikin. I would like an idea how to get started.

> Let $f:L \rightarrow L$ be a diagonalizable operator with distinct eigenvalues. Prove that any operator $g: L\rightarrow  L$ such that $gf = fg$ can be represented in the form of a polynomial of $f$.

Comment: Without further data that seems to be false...

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe that all eigenvalues must be distinct

Comment: Yes, it is given the operator's spectrum is simple...and that seems to mean all the eigenvalues are different.

Comment: @Mrcrg why did you say this in the comments but not go back and include it in the question?

Comment: This is one of those mildly infuriating things that if a person encounters five or more in a single day they will throw a chair out the window

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $f$ is the identity. Then the equality $g\circ f=f\circ g$ holds for every $g\colon L\longrightarrow L$. However, it is not true that every operator is a polynomial on $f$. So, the statement is false.

Comment: I believe that all eigenvalues must be distinct

Comment: Sure. Under that assumption, the statement holds. But you did not include that assumption in your question.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to add that assumption, then I suggest that you ask it as another question.

Answer (score 2):

If the eigenvalues are distinct then you should edit the question; in that case it's simple: Say $b_1,\dots,b_n$ is a basis for $L$ and $fb_j=\lambda_jb_j$. Now $$f(gb_j)=g(fb_j)=\lambda_jgb_j.$$Since the $\lambda_j$-eigenspace has dimension $1$ this shows that $gb_j=\alpha_jb_j$ for some scalar $\alpha_j$.

There is a polynomial $p$ such that $p(\lambda_j)=\alpha_j$ for all $j$; hence $gb_j=p(f)b_j$, so $g=p(f)$.